# How to learn to create General (Functional) Shadings wifth pgf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-core, shading

In the section called General (Functional) Shadings in the  PGF/TikZ manual, there is an "explanation" of the command to create a general functional shading.

The author of this section assumes that the TeX user knows how to use the type 4 function.

But I don't, so where can I learn? Can somebody explain how to create a shading with this command?

Comment: The pgfmanual mentions a number of caveats with the functional shadings (`These shadings are the least portable of all and they put the heaviest burden of the renderer.
They are slow and, possibly, will not print correctly!`). Maybe you could explain what you are trying to achieve so people might suggest other avenues to explore.

Comment: Also they will not render correctly in many PDF viewers.

Comment: @Jake: consider a function defined in a polar system like (1/r)*(cos(theta))^2. I'd like to create a rectangular shading that goes from red to blue that follow the previou equation.

Comment: @Azoun: With that function, there are a couple of problems due to the singularity at `r=0`. What value do you want to assign to red, what value to blue? What do you want to do near `r=0`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type 4 functions mentioned in the TikZ manual are what are called Postscript Calculator Functions, a subset of Postscript which is supported by the PDF specification.  The actual subset is described in chapter 7 of the [*PDF 1.7 reference manual*](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). Type 4 functions themselves are described in detail in Chapter 4 of the [*Postscript Language Reference 3rd Edition*](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/PLRM.pdf).

Unless you are well versed in the Postscript language, I don't think this aspect of PGF is very accessible.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know any good place from where to learn all the material, but I can try to give you a few pointers. The following comes with the caveat that I only dabbled in writing shaders a bit and am certainly no expert on this topic.

Abstractly, a functional shader is given by a function *f*: R → [0,1]³, where R is some subset of ℝ² (usually a rectangle) and [0,1]³ is interpreted as the space of all RGB colors. So *f* assigns each point of the shaded region a color. Your job is to provide *f*. Then, *each time* the image is rendered the viewer evaluates *f* on (the point of R corresponding to) each pixel inside the image and colors the pixel with the returned color.

In PGF, you'd specify such a function with `\pgfdeclareshading`:

```
\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading
    {⟨shading name⟩}
    {⟨lower left corner⟩}{⟨upper right corner⟩}
    {⟨initialization code⟩}
    {⟨code for the actual shading⟩}
```

Here `{⟨lower left corner⟩}{⟨upper right corner⟩}` specifies the rectangular domain R ⊆ ℝ², `⟨initialization code⟩` can be ignored for the moment (see the PGF manual for details) and `⟨code for the actual shading⟩` is the difficult part.

The actual code for the shading has to be written in a very restricted subset of [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript#The_language). Presumably it is so restricted to force you to only write very simple function. Even so, be aware that the rendering of a shading can take a very long time (and has to be done each time the document is displayed).

PostScript is a [stack-based programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_language). If you are not familiar with this concept, try reading the Wikipedia article on that subject. If you are not used to stack-based languages, be aware that writing even very simple functions can be a challenge.

The allowed subset is listed in the PGF manual or the PDF reference: basically you only have math functions, stack manipulation operators and if-then-else at your disposal. You'll notice that there are no loops and variables. The operations themselves are described in section 3.6 of the [Postscript Language Reference 3rd Edition](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/PLRM.pdf) or presumably any other good book about PostScript (see for example [Wikipedia's references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript#External_links)).

At the start of the execution of the shader function the stack consists of the x and y coordinate of a point in R (in big points) and after the execution the top three stack elements should be real values in [0,1] which are treated as red, green and blue component of the color of this point.

Comment: Many thanks for the stack-based programming language wikipedia page. I didn't know this concept before.

Comment: @Azoun ever looked at what the URL of this forum is? ;)

Answer (score 10):

As a different approach to creating complicated shadings: You could use a three-dimensional pgfplots plot that is viewed from above, and use the `colormap` feature to get the colours.

For example, the shading mentioned in your comment, `(1/r)*(cos(theta))^2` in a polar coordinate system, could be achieved like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={redblue}{rgb(0cm)=(1,0,0); rgb(1cm)=(0,0,1)}}
\begin{axis}[
    view={0}{90},
    width=7cm, height=7cm,
    xmin=-0.707, xmax=0.707, ymin=-0.707, ymax=0.707,
    hide axis]
\addplot3 [
    domain=0:360,
    y domain=0.1:1,
    surf,
    shader=interp
    ] ({y*cos(x)},
        {y*sin(x)},
        {(1/y)*(cos(x))^2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that there is a singularity at `r=0` due to the term `1/r`, that's why there's a hole in the middle. The smaller the hole, the less interesting the shading.