# Using tikz to draw a rectangle with black-white gradient in form of Gaussian

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to make a rectangle, longer horizontally than vertically, that is black at the left and right ends and whitish in the center. I don't want a linear gradient change from black to white (and back), but a change in the form of a bell curve.

I've seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28850/how-to-learn-to-create-general-functional-shadings-wifth-pgf), which seems very general, but I could not alter the arbitrary function to a simple gaussian. I am hoping there is a simpler way.

The following is the best I could manage:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex   
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}                                     
\begin{document}   
                                                  
\begin{pgfpicture}                                                   
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshadingD}  {20pt}{color(0pt)=(black); color(40pt)=(white)}   
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshadingA}  {20pt}{color(0pt)=(white); color(40pt)=(black)} 
\pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}] {\pgfuseshading{myshadingD}}    
\pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{2cm}{0cm}] {\pgfuseshading{myshadingA}}      
\end{pgfpicture}       
                                            
\end{document}
```

Which creates something like this:

[image]

Comment: you might benefit from displaying a minimal example and/or some type of starting visual if you wanna get help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since defining a `\pgfdeclarefunctionshading` is a lot of math and PostScript, I'd just precompute a few values.

I'm using LibreOffice Calc since it's just the easiest tool I have on hand and I can use its function to create the necessary

```
color(<length>)=(<outer>!<share>!<inner>);
```

declarations in a seperate column which I just need to copy to my TeX source.

For the `\pgftext{\pgfuseshading{<name>}}` command I will be calculation 41 values between `0pt` and `40pt` which will be mapped to −π and +π.

Since [PGF transforms the shading on a path](https://tikz.dev/base-shadings#pgf.back/pgfshadepath) somewhat, we'll use `25bp` and `75bp` for the same ±π range (and in total 51 values).

The shading that's *usable* in PGF/TikZ I call `Gaussian` (compared to `gaussian` for `\pgftext`.

The keys `gauss outer color` and `gauss inner color` can be used to change the colors.

The last example in my document compared the `Gaussian` shading with the default (and strictly linear) `axis` shading.

Maybe this could have done with less points and it would still be enough but it is certainly less work than to code in PostScript.

### Code

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[black]{gaussian}{20pt}{
color(0pt)=(black!99);color(1pt)=(black!99);color(2pt)=(black!98);color(3pt)=(black!97);color(4pt)=(black!96);
color(5pt)=(black!94);color(6pt)=(black!91);color(7pt)=(black!88);color(8pt)=(black!83);color(9pt)=(black!78);
color(10pt)=(black!71);color(11pt)=(black!63);color(12pt)=(black!55);color(13pt)=(black!45);color(14pt)=(black!36);
color(15pt)=(black!27);color(16pt)=(black!18);color(17pt)=(black!11);color(18pt)=(black!5);color(19pt)=(black!1);
color(20pt)=(black!0);color(21pt)=(black!1);color(22pt)=(black!5);color(23pt)=(black!11);color(24pt)=(black!18);
color(25pt)=(black!27);color(26pt)=(black!36);color(27pt)=(black!45);color(28pt)=(black!55);color(29pt)=(black!63);
color(30pt)=(black!71);color(31pt)=(black!78);color(32pt)=(black!83);color(33pt)=(black!88);color(34pt)=(black!91);
color(35pt)=(black!94);color(36pt)=(black!96);color(37pt)=(black!97);color(38pt)=(black!98);color(39pt)=(black!99);
color(40pt)=(black!99)}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[gauss@border,gauss@center]{Gaussian}{100bp}{
color(0bp)=(gauss@border!100!gauss@center);color(25bp)=(gauss@border!99!gauss@center);color(26bp)=(gauss@border!99!gauss@center);
color(27bp)=(gauss@border!98!gauss@center);color(28bp)=(gauss@border!98!gauss@center);color(29bp)=(gauss@border!97!gauss@center);
color(30bp)=(gauss@border!96!gauss@center);color(31bp)=(gauss@border!94!gauss@center);color(32bp)=(gauss@border!92!gauss@center);
color(33bp)=(gauss@border!90!gauss@center);color(34bp)=(gauss@border!87!gauss@center);color(35bp)=(gauss@border!83!gauss@center);
color(36bp)=(gauss@border!79!gauss@center);color(37bp)=(gauss@border!74!gauss@center);color(38bp)=(gauss@border!68!gauss@center);
color(39bp)=(gauss@border!62!gauss@center);color(40bp)=(gauss@border!55!gauss@center);color(41bp)=(gauss@border!47!gauss@center);
color(42bp)=(gauss@border!40!gauss@center);color(43bp)=(gauss@border!32!gauss@center);color(44bp)=(gauss@border!25!gauss@center);
color(45bp)=(gauss@border!18!gauss@center);color(46bp)=(gauss@border!12!gauss@center);color(47bp)=(gauss@border!7!gauss@center);
color(48bp)=(gauss@border!3!gauss@center);color(49bp)=(gauss@border!1!gauss@center);color(50bp)=(gauss@border!0!gauss@center);
color(51bp)=(gauss@border!1!gauss@center);color(52bp)=(gauss@border!3!gauss@center);color(53bp)=(gauss@border!7!gauss@center);
color(54bp)=(gauss@border!12!gauss@center);color(55bp)=(gauss@border!18!gauss@center);color(56bp)=(gauss@border!25!gauss@center);
color(57bp)=(gauss@border!32!gauss@center);color(58bp)=(gauss@border!40!gauss@center);color(59bp)=(gauss@border!47!gauss@center);
color(60bp)=(gauss@border!55!gauss@center);color(61bp)=(gauss@border!62!gauss@center);color(62bp)=(gauss@border!68!gauss@center);
color(63bp)=(gauss@border!74!gauss@center);color(64bp)=(gauss@border!79!gauss@center);color(65bp)=(gauss@border!83!gauss@center);
color(66bp)=(gauss@border!87!gauss@center);color(67bp)=(gauss@border!90!gauss@center);color(68bp)=(gauss@border!92!gauss@center);
color(69bp)=(gauss@border!94!gauss@center);color(70bp)=(gauss@border!96!gauss@center);color(71bp)=(gauss@border!97!gauss@center);
color(72bp)=(gauss@border!98!gauss@center);color(73bp)=(gauss@border!98!gauss@center);color(74bp)=(gauss@border!99!gauss@center);
color(75bp)=(gauss@border!99!gauss@center);color(100bp)=(gauss@border!100!gauss@center)}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  gauss outer color/.code=\colorlet{gauss@border}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{Gaussian}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue},
  gauss inner color/.code=\colorlet{gauss@center}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{Gaussian}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\makeatother
\colorlet{gauss@border}{black}
\colorlet{gauss@center}{white}

\begin{document}

Let $a$ and $b$ be the first and the last length of the shading which should be mapped to the range $z = (-\pi, \pi)$ then is
\begin{equation}
z = \pi \left(2 \frac{i-a}{b-a}-1\right).
\end{equation}
The share of the color in range $c = (0, 100)$ is then
\begin{equation}
  c(i) = 100 \left(1- \frac{\phi(z)}{\phi(0)}\right).
\end{equation}

\texttt{gaussian}: $a = 0\,\mathrm{pt}$, $b = 40\,\mathrm{pt}$ \quad
\texttt{Gaussian}: $a = 25\,\mathrm{bp}$, $b = 75\,\mathrm{bp}$

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=20pt,y=20pt]
\pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}]{\pgfuseshading{gaussian}}
\draw[overlay,very thick,red] plot[domain=-1:1, samples=100] 
  (\x,{exp(-(\x*\x*pi*pi)/2)/sqrt(2*pi)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz\shade[shading=Gaussian] (0,0) rectangle (3,1);

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[gauss outer color=green, gauss inner color=magenta]
  (0, 0) coordinate (bl) rectangle ++(2.5, 1) coordinate (tr);

\fill[magenta] ([shift=(up:1)] bl) rectangle ++(1.25, -.25)
  ++ (down:.5) rectangle ++(1.25, -.25);
\shade[left color=green, right color=magenta]
  (bl) rectangle ++ (1.25, .25) coordinate (m);
\shade[left color=magenta, right color=green]
  (tr) rectangle ++ (-1.25, -.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is great, but unfortunately I need to compute several different rectangles like this with different standard deviations. I will accept your answer and try it this way if nobody can help me with PostScript and type 4 functions.

Comment: @Wapiti It looks like you can pass no variable to a shading unless it's a color. That said, in the PostScript function you could use values of the color to calculate something without actually using the color. Otherwise, you could fake it the same way with a `path picture` and a lot of calculations (or Lua).

Answer (score 2):

A shading that is faked

1. by using filled `rectangle`s: `fake shading` or
2. by using shaded `rectangle`s: `real fake shading`.

[Something's up with `path picture`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1177) which is why `real fake shading` has an empty `\shade;` in it, otherwise the first shaded rectangle does not get shaded.

Except for that `\shade;` command I'm using PGF macros to, hopefully, speed up the compilation.

We can set the function to shade something with `fakeshading/function=<func>` where `<func>` evaluates `\x` for values between `0` and `1` to values between `0` and `100`.

Notice, that the `fake shading` with a step of `.01` one can still see edges the `real fake shading` uses a step of `.05`.

### Code

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\pgfqkeys{/tikz/fakeshading}{
  colorA/.initial=black,
  colorB/.initial=white,
  function/.initial={%
    (100-100*phi(6.28318530717959*\x-3.14159265358979)/0.398942280401433)},
  step/.initial=.01}
\makeatletter
\def\fake@shading@function{max(0,min(100,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fakeshading/function}))}
\tikzset{
  declare function={phi(\z)=exp(-\z*\z/2)/sqrt(2*pi);},
  fake shading/.default=,real fake shading/.default=,
  fake shading/.style={ path picture={%
      \tikzset{every fake shading/.try,/tikz/fakeshading/.cd,#1}\fake@shading@setup
      \pgfmathmultiply@{.5}{\fake@shading@step}% half step length
      \let\fake@shading@halfstep\pgfmathresult
      \foreach \x[expand list,evaluate={\y=\fake@shading@function;}]
        in {0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fakeshading/step},...,1.001} {
%       \fill[color=fake@shading@A!\y!fake@shading@B] (\x-\fake@shading@halfstep,0)
%                           rectangle ++(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fakeshading/step},1);
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointxy{\x-\fake@shading@halfstep}{0}}%
                         {\pgfpointxy{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fakeshading/step}}{1}}
        \pgfsetfillcolor{fake@shading@A!\y!fake@shading@B}\pgfusepath{fill}}}},
  real fake shading/.style={path picture={%
      \tikzset{every real fake shading/.try,/tikz/fakeshading/.cd,#1}\fake@shading@setup
      \pgfmathmultiply@{\fake@shading@step}{2}\let\fake@shading@doublestep\pgfmathresult
      \def\x{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\fake@shading@lasty{\fake@shading@function}%
      \shade;% the first shade doesn't want to
      \foreach \x[expand list,evaluate={\y=\fake@shading@function;},
        remember=\y as \lasty (initially \fake@shading@lasty)%
      ] in {\fake@shading@step,\fake@shading@doublestep,...,1.001} {
        \pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@axis@top}{fake@shading@A!\lasty!fake@shading@B}%
        \pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@axis@bottom}{fake@shading@A!\y!fake@shading@B}%
        \pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@axis@middle}{tikz@axis@top!50!tikz@axis@bottom}%
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointxy{\x}{0}}{\pgfpointxy{-\fake@shading@step}{1}}
        \pgfshadepath{axis}{90}\pgfusepath{}}}}}
\def\fake@shading@setup{%
  \pgftransformreset
  \colorlet{fake@shading@A}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fakeshading/colorA}}%
  \colorlet{fake@shading@B}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fakeshading/colorB}}%
  \pgfextract@process\tikz@temp{% setting up coordinate system
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}
                 {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}}%
  \pgfsetxvec{\tikz@temp\pgf@y0pt }\pgfsetyvec{\tikz@temp\pgf@x0pt }%
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\fake@shading@step{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fakeshading/step}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{every real fake shading/.append style={fakeshading/step=.05}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fake shading]  (0,1) rectangle (5,2);
\path[real fake shading] (0,0) rectangle (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fakeshading/function=100*((2*\x-1)^2)]% x² between (-1 and 1)
\path[fake shading]  (0,1) rectangle (5,2);
\path[real fake shading] (0,0) rectangle (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fakeshading/function=50*(sin(2*\x*360)+1)]% (sin x between 0 and 4pi)
\path[fake shading]  (0,1) rectangle (5,2);
\path[real fake shading] (0,0) rectangle (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikz\shade[real fake shading] (0,0) rectangle (3,1);
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[real fake shading={colorA=green, colorB=magenta}]
  (0, 0) coordinate (bl) rectangle ++(2.5, 1) coordinate (tr);

\fill[magenta] ([shift=(up:1)] bl) rectangle ++(1.25, -.25)
  ++ (down:.5) rectangle ++(1.25, -.25);
\shade[left color=green, right color=magenta]
  (bl) rectangle ++ (1.25, .25) coordinate (m);
\shade[left color=magenta, right color=green]
  (tr) rectangle ++ (-1.25, -.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

The ones with the `fake shading` don't look good after the converting and have some artefacts.

[image]

The `real fake shading` doesn't have the same problem:

[image]
[image]